# POSTFIX main.cf permission denied

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, smtp

I am trying to set up a postfix server for smtp relay. Centos 5.5

I have followed http://mhawthorne.net/posts/postfix-configuring-gmail-as-relay.html but am getting a FAILED error when trying to restart or reload postfix.

When I do:

```
cat maillog
```

I get:

```
fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: Permission denied
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
chown postfix /etc/postfix/main.cf
chmod u+rwx /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

After that, I do:

```
ls -l /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Which gives me:

```
-rwx------. 1 postfix anotheruser 27531 Apf 29 12:19 /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

No dice. Same error. I even tried temporarily doing chmod 777 but got same error.

Any ideas on the permissions problem? I am assuming it is running the service as the postfix user.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost certainly to do with SELinux. I bet you moved your main.cf into that location.

Try running `restorecon -v /etc/postfix/main.cf` to fix the labelling.

Comment: To do a fast verification if SELinux it's the cause, disable it temporarily like this: `sudo setenforce 0` If now everything works then SELinux it's the cause. Run `sudo setenforce 1` to enable SELinux again and solve the problem as suggested

Comment: I had to fix the SELinux context manually. This can be done using
  sudo chcon -v -u system_u -r object_r -t postfix_etc_t /etc/postfix/main.cf
As it was:
  -rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 main.cf
This was before I realised I had to do the restorecon with '-r' or on a specific file.

Comment: None of that worked for me on Alma Linux 9

Answer (score 18):

In my case, the other answers didn't helped me, because I already had the context for those files correctly.
Even if the file's correct context are applied, you'll also need to be sure the Apache user has SELinux permission to send mails.
Specifically there is a SELinux configuration that need to be turned on.

1. Verify if the setting is on or off: `getsebool httpd_can_sendmail`
2. If you got `httpd_can_sendmail --> off` you can enable this setting this way: 
   `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1`

*-P* in the above command means *Persistent* (across reboots)

Comment: This was exactly the issue in my LEMP stack!

Comment: Cheers. This solved my problem too.

Comment: Bingo! ran into this when setting up a new Rocky Linux 9 server. This instruction should be a part of all postfix setup instructions where SELinux is used.

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely related to SELinux access control. CentOS has "Enforcing" SELinux mode by default. Please check the status of SELinux with comnand:

```
# sestatus
```

If the output something like this:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

You need to to change security context for main.cf and probably other postfix configuration flies. On my machine it is set to:

```
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:postfix_etc_t:s0 /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Try these to set proper context:

```
 # chcon -v -u system_u -r object_r -t postfix_etc_t /etc/postfix/main.cf
 # restorecon -v -R  /etc/postfix/
```

To verify:

```
 # ls -Z /etc/postfix/
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case was because selinux didn't allow apache (PHP) to send emails.  Fixed with:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail=1
```

Comment: Why the down point? I had the same problem and found a way to fix it...